# What is the difference between $P(AB)$ and $P(A|B)$?

Tags: probability

I know that $P(A|B)$ means "the probability of $A$ given $B$", but I see the notation $P(AB)$ often and I'm not sure if that's just another way of writing it or if it means something I don't know yet.

Comment: I've never seen $P(AB)$. They might mean $P(A \cap B)$ (i.e., the probability of both events $A$ and $B$ occuring). This is also sometimes written $P(A, B)$.

Comment: $P(A|B)$ is the probability of $A$ occurring given that $B$ _has already occurred_ while $P(AB)=P(A\cap B)$ is the probability of $A$ and $B$ both occurring together without any premise of either of them being already occurred. So, we have, by the rule of product for probabilities that, $$P(AB)=P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)=P(B)P(A|B)$$

Comment: $P(A \ \text{and} \ B)=P(A\cap B)=P(A,B)=P(AB)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(AB)$ is probably referring to the probability of $A$ *and* $B$, i.e. $P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Does this mean the intersection? e.g. A = {1, 2, 3} B = {1, 3, 5} P(AB) = {1}

Comment: $P(AB)$ refers to the **probability** of the intersection. Also, the intersection in your example is $\{1,3\}$.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. Thanks for your help.